# Not able to tick items in SP Flash Tool after selecting scatter .txt file.How to check Boxes?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, flashtool, mediatek

I download SP Flash Tool And recovery file zip,extracted recovery zip which contain three files:
1)scatter .txt file
2)recovery image file
3)recovery read me file
After that i opened tool.exe and select the scatter file but don't able to tick the recovery name object[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a file to write each partition you want to select. Double click on the location column for the partition you want to write to and select an img file, e.g. twrp.